# Unit tests with GWT 2.6.0 failing when building with JDK 8

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-test-utils

We inherited an old application which still runs on JDK 7. We want to use JDK 8 but for some weird reason the tests don't work anymore when building with JDK 8. It starts to complain that certain anonymous classes cannot be found:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/some/package/client/widget/SomeClass$1
```

I read somewhere that you shouldn't use anonymous classes with GWT and JDK 8. I tried changing that but still it keeps complaining that it cannot find the class :-(.

```
        Collections.sort(objects, new Comparator<ClientObject>() {
        public int compare(ClientObject object1, ClientObject object2) {
                int result = 0;
                if ((object1 != null) && (object2 != null)) {
                    result = object1.getTranslation().compareTo(object2.getTranslation());
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
```

The code block above is the culprit it seems. But have no idea why. I also tried upgrading to newer versions of GWT but that causes other NoClassDefFoundError errors during test. Does anybody know what we are doing wrong?

For the test cases we use gwt-test-utils.

Comment: "I read somewhere that you shouldn't use anonymous classes with GWT and JDK 8." Where did you read that? GWT itself uses anonymous classes all over, and Java8 is supported fully in GWT 2.8.

Comment: Somewhere on Stackoverflow someone suggested this. But in the end it didn't help. I was already aware of that GWT 2.8 supports Java 8 but that's not what this question is about. The problem is that when you just switch the JDK to Java 8 on a project with GWT 2.6 and use gwt-test-utils for your testing for some weird reason it doesn't find the anonymous classes anymore although they are there. Even if you extract the anonymous into a separate file as a seprate class it complains it cannot find it.

Comment: If the anonymous class is not found should be because it has been invalidated, use debug log level and try to see why it is invalidated. Might be some other thing, but this looks the most probably.

Comment: What do you mean with invalidated? Where am I supposed to look for this information?

Comment: If GWT is marking the anon types as unable to be used, then in the GWT compiler log there will be errors (especially if you have it in strict mode, or have the debug or trace logs turned on). However this looks to me like it is part of the "gwt-test-utils" project, and not part of the GWT compilation at all.